# Add Total Label top of stacked bar/column in Shield UI Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid, shieldui

I just started using Shield UI and I would like to add total labels on each stacked bar.  any ideas?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out if anyone else is having a similar issue.  I added an empty series as my first series.  see below:

```
<cc1:ChartBarSeries >
   <Settings StackMode="Normal">
      <DataPointText Enabled="true" Color="white" Format="**{point.stackTotal}"** Y="-10"/>
   </Settings>
</cc1:ChartBarSeries>
```